# WYSIWYG editor with image upload for "Normal Users"

Tags: uploads, bbpress, wysiwyg

Can someone tell me is there a plugin doing this?(This has been asked over 6 years from bbpress.org)
I have tried lots of plugins but no one does exactly what I need,
1) A WYSIWYG editor in bbpress for normal users(frontend).
2) With an image “upload” feature, but is not working like an attachment like “GD bbPress Attachments”.
3) All the uploaded images will be separated by folder(user name or individual name for an user).This is to avoid user use images from other users.

I am also happy to know the reason if this is impossible this meanwhile, like wordpress official has a consideration on it’s risks.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar functionality. I want BuddyPress users to upload image, make a custom post and set the uploaded image as the post's featured image.

It is possible to do this, do not see why not. Maybe somebody will be able to post a complete out-of-box solution for you.

In the meantime, if you are code-savvy, the way I would approach this task would be:

- Find a WYSIWIG (Black Studio's Tiny MCE?)
- Find a flexible file
  upload plugin (I may go with this one
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/) that allows you to
  choose store location and other options.
- Modify bbPress part that
  handles uploads to render the new plugins on frontend.
- Further extend
  bbPress's backend, use a filter (maybe an action (?)) hook that gives
  you ability to intercept new topic's default meta data so you can
  extend it and use the data collected from the two plugins instead of
  default (i.e. the HTML text and image URL).

This is not an answer, but hope it gives the OP an overview of scope of the work required to get this done.

Comment: Sorry, but this is far from an answer. It's more a task description pretty close to the actual question.

Comment: I know, I don't have an answer. It's help towards one, hopefully.

Comment: The question itself is off topic (and closed) anyway. But for further answers: Keep in mind that if you ain't got an answer, then please don't use the "answer" field. Add a comment instead - you will gain that ability after receiving some upvotes on _real_ answers. This is how the system works. Thanks for trying to help anyway.